# PowerShell - Provide Real Time Output to Console from within ForEach-Object or any Loop

Tags: powershell, output

I have a long process that updates thousands of records originating from the Import-Csv cmdlet.

During this long process I would like to be updated as to the number of records the Loop is currently at.  I want some code that would reside within the `ForEach-Object` to provide incremental output during the processing of the data to tell the user some sort of status as to how many records have been processed rather than waiting the unknown amount of time only to see the output after the script is finished executing.

The only option I've found is to use `Write-Progress` however I have not been able to get it to work using a `ForEach-Object`.  The only way I've got this to work is using the very simple example I found that demonstrates this using a simple for loop.  Really in the end I just want to send a *blip* to the Console just letting me know how many records have been processed (perhaps after every 1000 records or so).  I don't need anything fancy like Write-Progress but would still be curious as to why my code does not work.

## Example code that works (not very useful in this state)

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++ ) {
     Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i
     Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150
}
```

## More complex version I cannot get to work

I don't understand the behavior I'm seeing when I run the below.  The output slowly crawls onto the Console and when it becomes complete it ends at 45% or some percentage that is NOT 100%. - Fixed this piece using suggestion in comments from Mathias and mclayton.

The remaining issues after applying those much needed suggestions is that if there is nothing to process the script runs so fast that it outputs a percentage that is very low and it never gets to the full 100%.  I applied `[Math]::Ceiling( ($i/$ProcessData.count) * 100 )` which fixed the issue of the script showing 99.3355888% as it never truly made it to a full 100% inside the loop.

The other issue is still the strange crawling output once the script is started.

```
#Declare File Paths
$SourceFile = "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData.tsv"

$ProcessData = Import-Csv $SourceFile -Delimiter "`t"

Write-Host $ProcessData.count

$ProcessData | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    # Set the $i counter variable to zero.
    $i = 0
    } -Process {

    # Increment the $i counter variable which is used to create the progress bar.
    $i = $i + 1
    # Determine the completion percentage
    
    if ( ($i % 100) -eq 0 ) {
        $Completed = [Math]::Ceiling( ($i/$ProcessData.count) * 100 )
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Records" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $Completed
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
    
    #$_.record_id
    #$Completed
}
```

The example I was attempting to replicate above came from this link (example 3): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.3
And also when I run Example 3 it almost locked up Visual Studio Code and also populates the Terminal with a weird crawling output, meaning the data slowly populates in the terminal.

## Some RAW Tsv Data in a file "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData.csv"

```
_record_number  record_id   id_testing  Notes   IntakeComplete
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
111 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
222 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
444 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
333 6   5   "We will not be testing because of covid 19"    1
```

## TL;DR

Below is the actual code I applied the ProgressBar code to.  I'm open to any improvements you might be able to provide such as how to better obtain the Count of rows in the file being imported.  Mathias suggested I directly Pipe this into the ForEach-Object however I don't know how to get the Total number of rows if I do that.

```
#Declare File Paths
$SourceFile = "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData.tsv"
$ExportFile = "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData_Updated.tsv"
$FormatFile = "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData.fmt"
$ErrorFile  = "C:\DataTemp\SomeTestData_Errors.log"

# Adjust this according to file input size
$progressInterval = 1000 # 1000 meaning 1000 Lines or Records in the tsv/csv

# variable to keep track of the record count
$recordCount = 0
$totalRecords = 0

# kick off the progress activity
$activity = "Processing '$SourceFile'"
Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status 'Import initiated!' # This can be short lived and not noticed depending on the time it takes to import


#---------- 1 Add Column to the beginning of the CSV/TSV file for the Identity Column.  The Export-Csv Commandlet by default also Replaces NewLine_LF (\n) with Cariage Return Line Feed CRLF (\r\n)

# The main purpose of the below is to add a Column at the beginning of the file as a placeholder for the Identity Column in the Staging Table.
# The below will read the Tab Delimited file having EOL Characters as New Lines/Line Feeds \n and turn them into CRLF (Cariage Return, Line Feeds) \r\n.
# It will also remove almost all of the double quotes it finds in the file.  The -UseQuotes option is not perfect and so we still have to clean
#  up the data Post Import and remove any Leading or Trailing Double Quotes using a SQL Update.

$ProcessData = Import-Csv $SourceFile -Delimiter "`t"

$totalRecords = $ProcessData.count

$ProcessData | Select-Object @{Name='_record_number';Expression={'999'}},* | #Example Adding new column to End Select-Object *,@{Name='column3';Expression={'setvalue'}} 
ForEach-Object {
    
    # increment record counter
    $recordCount++

    # Loop Thru ALL field values and if NOT Null preform a replace to remove TABs and Double Quotes from within each field
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        if ( ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($property.Value)  ) {
            # Replace Tabs, Double Quotes, Cariage Returns and New Lines within Fields and Trim
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Trim() -replace '`t|\"|`r|`n',''
            
            # Scan fields for dates.  If a Date is found make sure the Year is greater than 1900.  If not update the year to 1900
            if ( ( $property.Value -as [datetime] ) -and ( [datetime]$property.Value -lt (Get-Date 1900-01-01) ) ) {
                $property.Value = (Get-Date $property.Value -Year 1900).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
            }
        }
    }   
    
    # check if it's time to update the status message
    if ($recordCount % $progressInterval -eq 0) {
        Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status "Records processed so far: $recordCount/$totalRecords"
    }
    # Check if it's the last record
    if ($recordCount -eq $totalRecords) {
        Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status "Total Records: $recordCount.  Preparing bcp.exe import"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 4000
    }

    # Output the updated object
    $_
} |
# Write-Host $_ # Use Write-Host to view piped object Post Update from the foreach loop for testing and verification
Export-Csv $ExportFile -Delimiter "`t" -UseQuotes Never -NoTypeInformation

# shut down the progress bar
Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Completed

Write-Host "Total number of Records: $recordCount"

#---------- 2 Import Using Format File ---------------

$global:pass = "password"

# Use an Import File to Bulk Import Data

bcp Server.Schema.Table IN $ExportFile `
-f $FormatFile `
-e $ErrorFile `
-S LOCALPC\SQLEXPRESS `
-U sa -P $pass `
-F 2 `
#-L 1000
```

Comment: It stops at "45% Complete:" because there's 45 rows in your test data - change `-Status "$i% Complete:"` to `-Status "${Completed}% Complete:"` :)

Comment: +1 for what @MathiasR.Jessen said, plus, you don’t need to update the progress bar for *every* record - that *massively* slows down the whole process as you spend all your time updating the progress bar rather than processing records. Maybe do something like ```if( ($i % 100) -eq 0) { … update progress … }``` to only update progress every 100 (or whatever) records…

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I applied your suggestion.  I don't understand why that works or what that syntax is called?  Wrapping the variable with curly braces?  What is that?

Comment: @mclayton I didn't know how to do that until I saw your comment.  Such a perfect suggestion.  My issue now is depending on how heavy of a load the processing incurs the script if run without any processing finishes so fast that the progress bar ends up showing 14% or nothing.  If I remove the `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1` I almost get no output.  In a real world situation the processing will take longer but if there is a small file how can I get the output to correctly show 100%?

Comment: The curly brackets act as qualifiers for the variable name, `${Completed}` is the same variable as `$Completed`, I just added them out of habit, not important. The important part is that you use `$Completed` rather than `$i` to report the progress in percentage :)

Comment: Also - is the `Write-Progress` really the ONLY thing we have to show some sort of output during the processing of a loop?

Comment: @CodeNovice You can do whatever you want from inside a loop body - you could update the title bar of the window, play a song made of `[Console]::Beep`'s, display text on the console with `Write-Host`, send an annoying email to your boss every 20 iterations, etc. :)

Comment: Please don't alter your question to present my suggestion as if it was part of your original sample code - now the answer I've posted doesn't make any sense

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My apologies.  I had done so prior to seeing your answer.  I did note that I added updates.  Regardless - I just reviewed your answer.  I think the crawling VS Code Terminal output is the the nature of the beast I suppose.  I didn't realize that I could use Write-Progress without the progress bar.  This makes it much more useful to me in my use case.   My only other issue is when little to no processing occurs there is NO output stating any percentage.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You mention to NOT save the data to a variable.  The reason I am initially saving it to a variable is so I can do a $myFile.Count to get the total number of records.  I couldn't figure out how to obtain the total Count from a `ForEach-Object`.  It's good to know how many records I have processed but if you don't know how many records remain you are still left wondering how much longer the script is going to be running for.  In my actual code I was originally piping it to `Select-Object` which then pipes it to the `ForEach-Object`.  How to get total count from `ForEach-Object`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I got in today with the task to set your answer you posted as the correct answer.  I see you deleted it.  Feel free to put it back and I would love to mark it as the correct answer.  It seems some have a stricter set of rules they set for themselves when using StackOverflow.  I'm just here to learn and have fun.  The `Fun` part is important and then the `Learning` part comes easier.

Comment: I'll happily undelete my answer as soon as you revert the `-Status "$i% Complete:"` to `-Status "${Completed}% Complete:"` change in your question :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done.  I have reverted that change.  I believe I did revert the correct one.  Let me know if I failed to revert the correct line but pretty sure that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not actually PowerShell reporting that progress completes at 45% - it's caused by the definition of the status message:

```
-Status "$i% Complete:"
```

`$i` is the record counter, not the calculated percentage.

Replace it with:

```
-Status "$Completed% Complete:"
```

... and it'll report the expect number.

---

> I have a long process that updates **thousands of records** originating from the Import-Csv cmdlet.

Then you probably want to:

- avoid reading the whole data set into memory
- avoid calling `Write-Progress` on each iteration

Since you just want to keep track of the processed record count, there's no need to attempt to report a completion percentage. Simply update the status message for every X records:

```
# adjust this according to input size
$progressInterval = 5

# variable to keep track of the record count - better named than `$i` if you ask me :)
$recordCount = 0

# kick off the progress activity
$activity = "Processing '$SourceFile'"
Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status 'Import initiated!'

# don't assign the imported data to a variable - start processing it right away instead!
Import-Csv $SourceFile -Delimiter "`t" |ForEach-Object {
  # increment record counter
  $recordCount++

  # check if it's time to update the status message
  if ($recordCount % $progressInterval -eq 0) {
    Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Status "Records processed so far: $recordCount"
  }

  # work on each record $_ here
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}

# shut down the progress bar
Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Completed
```

Comment: You mention to NOT save the data to a variable.  The reason I am initially saving it to a variable is so I can do a $myFile.Count to get the total number of records.  I couldn't figure out how to obtain the total Count from a ForEach-Object.  It's good to know how many records I have processed but if you don't know how many records remain you are still left wondering how much longer the script is going to be running for.

Comment: @CodeNovice Sorry, I misunderstood your request - your original question stated you just wanted a "count of files" along the way